# What does the 'M' mean in this code?

Tags: .htaccess, file, upload

I am trying to change my .htaccess file to have a larger upload limit, but I don't understand what the 'M' after the number stands for.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 80M
php_value post_max_size  80M
```

Comment: It stands for Megabytes

Answer (score 1):

M means MegaBytes
while
G means Gigabytes

However, if your servers run PHP in "CGI mode" as recommended by the PHP developers (not as an Apache module), so you can't use "php_value" or "php_flag" commands in .htaccess files. If you try to do so, you'll see an "internal server error" message

Comment: Oh, well what would I do in that case then?

Comment: Contact your sysadmin asking to increase that value on server side or trying to compress the file you're going to upload and then to decompress it once available on server side.